# Create separate file for each result

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I have a bash script as follows:

```
SITE_LIST=/home/wps/sites.txt 

for file in `cat $SITE_LIST`
    do
        /usr/bin/wpscan --update --no-color --url $file --disable-tls-checks --follow-redirection --enumerate utp > "$file".txt
    done
```

When I run this script I get the following output:

```
./wpscan_script_2: line 15: www.need_help.com: No such file or directory
./wpscan_script_2: line 15: www.need_help.com: No such file or directory
./wpscan_script_2: line 15: www.need_help.com: No such file or directory
./wpscan_script_2: line 15: www.need_help.com: No such file or directory
./wpscan_script_2: line 15: www.need_help.com: No such file or directory
./wpscan_script_2: line 15: www.need_help.com: No such file or directory
```

**Note** I replaced the actual sites with the site www.need_help for security. that is not the name of the actual sites

What I am trying do is pipe each outcome into its own file. I have currently been unsuccessful at this.

Comment: What are the contents of line 15 of `wpscan_script_2`?

Comment: @user000001  /usr/bin/wpscan --update --no-color --url $file --disable-tls-checks --follow-redirection --enumerate utp > "$file".txt I had some echo statements that were removed. Sorry about that

Comment: You should always double-quote shell variables... `--url "$file"`

Comment: Don't iterate over a file using a `for` loop; see [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: shellcheck.net would flag both the unquoted parameters and the `for` loop.

Comment: @chepner thanks i'll give that a try

Comment: Sry, I missed that you use the same variable as file and url, I updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure form the error that your file contains lines like: `www.need_help.com/xyz` (with `xyz` beeing anything, doesn't matter what)

Which means that in the end `"$file".txt` expends to `www.need_help.com/xyz.txt`.

So your script tryed to write the output to a file `xyz.txt` in the folder `www.need_help.com` and fails because the folder does not exist.

The error message was confusing but accurate: www.need_help.com: No such file or **directory**

You might want to replace all unwanted characters with something else, as an example only keeping letters numbers and dots

```
for url in `cat "$SITE_LIST"`
    do
        file="$(printf '%s' "$url" | sed 's/[^A-Za-z0-9\.]/_/g')"
        /usr/bin/wpscan --update --no-color --url "$url" --disable-tls-checks --follow-redirection --enumerate utp > "$file".txt
    done
```

You can modify the sed regex if there are to many replacements for your taste. But it should at least replace all `/` with e.g.: `sed 's#/#-#g'`.

EDIT: missed that you use $file as url as well